# curl command in scala to fletch password from vault

Tags: scala, curl

i have curl command as below

```
curl \
    --request POST --insecure \
    --data '{"role_id":"xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxx","secret_id":"xxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxx"}' \
    https://vault.us-west-2.shared-lab.aws.hcom/v1/auth/approle/login
```

i have transformed this code as shown below

```
      val jsonBody = new JSONObject()
      jsonBody.put("role_id", "xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxx")
      jsonBody.put("secret_id", "xxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxx")
      
      println("json" + jsonBody)
      val tokenCmd = Seq("curl", "-H", s"--request POST --insecure --data ", "-d", s"$jsonBody","https://vault.us-west-2.shared-lab.aws.hcom/v1/auth/approle/login")


      val tokenExtractor = tokenCmd.!!
      println("y is " +tokenExtractor)
      val VAULT_TOKEN =tokenExtractor.substring(173,199)
      println("token "+ VAULT_TOKEN)
      val cmd2 = Seq("curl", "-H", s"X-Vault-Token: ${VAULT_TOKEN}","https://vault.us-west-2.shared-lab.aws.hcom/v1/xxx/xxx/xxx")
```

the code works locally, but to get when ran in another server, its failing for the below reason.

App > curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not

App > establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and

App > how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

App > 21/09/06 18:58:57 main ERROR SparkSubmit$$anon$2: Exception thrown on spark-submit: Nonzero exit value: 60

App > java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 60

i am ready to use an insecure --insecure, but able to apply , is their any config i need to update. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any reason to not use a proper HTTP client library rather than cURL?

Comment: I did that but it's failing at bufferreader, after passing role id and secret id

Comment: The above curl command works in server as well

Comment: You can't put multiple arguments in the same string. Each string in the `Seq` must hold exactly one argument. So e.g. `"--request POST --insecure --data "` is wrong — that's four arguments in a single string.